# How to fade in/out certain parts of a d3 force-layout with select/options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, highlight, force-layout

My scenario is like this: I have a select box with options and a lovely D3 force layout visualisation.

I want to use the options to fade-in/out certain parts of my visualisation. I'm using jQuery for this particular situation like:

```
$("select.filter.tag").change(function() {
  var cls = "."+$(this).val();
  if(cls != "."){
    d3.selectAll(".node:not("+cls+"), .link:not("+cls+")").transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);

    d3.selectAll(".node"+cls+", .link"+cls).transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }
  else{
    d3.selectAll(".node, .link").transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 1)
  }
});
```

However this doesn't fade in/out any part of my visualisation. The certain part just disappears in a split second (this is in the latest version of Firefox, the code actually works with Chrome & Safari)

Preview: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/41566165/question/index.html

Is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace your transition().duration(500).style('opacity', 1) with jQuery's built in fadeIn/fadeOut with appropriate animation times in ms.

Check out the [jQuery FadeOut documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Fade Out Example:

```
$('.node:not("+cls+"), .link:not("+cls+")').fadeOut(900);
```

Fading in is very similar to fading out:

```
$('.node'+cls+', .link'+cls').fadeIn(900);
```